# Cast NSString to UIButton type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

Im trying to cast a string to a button type. Basically, Im looping through, say 5 buttons, named btn1,btn2..btn5. Here's the snippet:

```
- (IBAction)replaceImg
{
  UIButton* b;
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {       
    b = (UIButton*)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"btn%d",i]; //1!
    if([b isHighlighted])
      {
      int imgNo = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
      UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSStringstringWithFormat:@"%d.png", imgNo]];
      [b setImage:img forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
      }
    }
}
```

The line marked 1 is giving a problem, if I swap it with b = btn1, it works perfectly. Please help!
I couldnt find a way to access a button by its name either. Like UIImage has something like imageNamed.

Comment: Hi, if u change the button image on its click, you can use tags for buttons

Comment: Why are you casting string to a button?

Comment: @pratikshabhisikar It's likely just a beginner's misunderstanding as to how casting works and what it's for.

Comment: Coz I want to access the buttons by their names (btn1, btn2, ... btn5)..I don't know how else I could do it.

Comment: Go back a little bit. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @desdenova - looping through all five buttons to see which is higlighted and then changing its image.

Comment: ok. you don't need any of this. try [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Comment: Did you create your buttons with code or with interface builder? If with Interface Builder you don't need my code either.

Comment: I have done that, check last line. I would still need to find out which one is highlighted.

Comment: I'm not trying to be condescending, but you need to go back and read a book or some tutorials. You are completely misunderstanding the way casting works, what it's for and are ignoring the fact that the framework (UIKit) can do what you're trying to do with one line of code, mentioned by Desdenova.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I used arrays and got it.

Answer (score 1):

you can't cast `NSString` to `UIButton` because both are completely different type.

Use **tag** property of `UIView` to assign and unique number to each `UIButton` and at any point of time you could access them by using **viewWithTag** .

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'cast' an NSString to a button. To get specific buttons, or buttons by name, depends on how you created them. Store your created buttons into an array, or if they come from a NIB then gather their pointers into an array, then loop through the array of button pointers. Controls are also UIViews, so you can assign a numeric 'tag' to each button in Interface Builder then use UIView's viewWithTag: method to search for a specific view with a specific tag.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, guys, I tried using an array, but I got stuck with just their declaration (I'm very new to iphone app dev! Brainwashed by java, cpp and php ). Do I use property and sythesize for both, the array and the UIButton objects? and then use initWithobjects?

Comment: Better to avoid (@)property and (@)synthesize until you really grok Objective-C memory management and data types.

Answer (score 0):

An `NSString` isn't a `UIButton`, so casting it to one isn't going to work.  Well, it might work as far as *syntax* goes, but logic-wise, it will fail.  You simply cannot interact with an `NSString` the same way you can a `UIButton`.  If you need to find your button by name, then you can either retain pointers to those buttons (either in an array, a map, or just as plain instance variables, to name a few ways), or you could alternatively use something like [`viewWithTag:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html).